# Regex to get dynamic value

Tags: regex, jmeter

I have the following:

```
ame="javax.faces.ViewState" 
id="javax.faces.ViewState" 
value="-8634862596057466271:770782409007219889" autocomplete="off" />
```

I have written a regx to extract values that can be correlated:

```
id="javax\.faces\.ViewState" value="(-[0-9]+:[0-9]+)
```

But the issue is that sometimes response value changes to

```
value="8634862596057466271:770782409007219889"
```

and it is unable to extract.

Can someone help me with a regex that will handle both values?

Answer (score 1):

Just make the hyphen optional with the `?` quantifier:

```
(-?[0-9]+:[0-9]+)
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/sW2tT5/1)

`?` matches 0 or 1 characters specified by the preceding pattern.

Answer (score 1):

You should use [CSS/JQuery Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSS/JQuery_Extractor) configured this way:

- Ref Name : state
- CSS/JQuery expression : input[id=javax.faces.ViewState]
- Attribute : value
- Match No : 1